# find_next not capturing all <div> instances

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having an issue where not all  instances are captured within a relatively simply beautifulsoup scrape. What I am running is the below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as reqs

home_test = "https://fbref.com/en/matches/033092ef/Northampton-Town-Lincoln-City-August-4-2018-League-Two"
away_test = "https://fbref.com/en/matches/ea736ad1/Carlisle-United-Northampton-Town-August-11-2018-League-Two"

page_to_parse = home_test

page = reqs.get(page_to_parse)
status_code = page.status_code
status_code = str(status_code)
parse_page = bsoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

find_stats = parse_page.find_all('div',id="team_stats_extra")
print(find_stats)
for stat in find_stats:
    add_stats = stat.find_next('div').get_text()
    print(add_stats)
```

If you have a look at the first print, the scrape captures the part of the website that I'm after, however if you inspect the second print, half of the  instances in the earlier one aren't actually being taken on at all. I do not have any limits on this, so in theory it should take in all the right ones.

I've already testes quite a few different variants of find_next, find, or find_all, but the second loop find never takes all of them.

Results are always:

```
Northampton Lincoln City
12Fouls13
6Corners1
7Crosses2
89Touches80
```

Where it should take on the following instead:

```
Northampton Lincoln City
12Fouls13
6Corners1
7Crosses2
89Touches80

Northampton Lincoln City
2Offsides2
9Goal Kicks15
32Throw Ins24
18Long Balls23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_page.find_all` returns a list of one item, the WebElement with `id="team_stats_extra"`. The loop need to be on it's child elements

```
find_stats = parse_page.find_all('div', id="team_stats_extra")
all_stats = find_stats[0].find_all('div', recursive=False)
for stat in all_stats:
    print(stat.get_text())
```

If you have multiple tables use two loops

```
find_stats = parse_page.find_all('div', id="team_stats_extra")
for stats in find_stats:
    all_stats = stats.find_all('div', recursive=False)
    for stat in all_stats:
        print(stat.get_text())
```

Comment: This worked fantastically, thanks! Makes sense why it didn't originally work.

Answer (score 1):

`find_stats = parse_page.find_all('div',id="team_stats_extra")` actually returns only one block, so the next loop performs only one iteration.

You can change the way to select the div blocks with :

```
find_stats = parse_page.select('div#team_stats_extra > div')

print(len(find_stats))  # >>> returns 2

for stat in find_stats:
    add_stats = stat.get_text()
    print(add_stats)
```

---

To explain the selector `select('div#team_stats_extra > div')`, it is the same as :

- find the `div` block with the id `team_stats_extra`
- and select all direct children that are `div`

Answer (score 1):

With bs4 4.7.1+ you can use :has to ensure you get the appropriate divs with class `th` as a child so you have the appropriate elements to loop over

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://fbref.com/en/matches/033092ef/Northampton-Town-Lincoln-City-August-4-2018-League-Two')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

for div in soup.select('#team_stats_extra div:has(.th)'):
    print(div.get_text())
```